# How do story-related dreams happen?

Tags: science

I am curious to know how dreams happen in our mind particularly when we sleep. I read many fictional stories and when I went to sleep after finishing the book, I used to get dreams in which I was the superhero whom I read about in the book.

e.g I read Harry Potter Part 1, and I would have a dream of me as Harry Potter.

Why does this type of dream happen to me? Is it common for all people whom read fictional stories?

Answer (score 3):

The current theories about dreaming revolve around recent discoveries in brain research. As I understand it, dreams occur during the part of the sleep cycle where the brain is managing memories. Data is being copied from short term memory to long term memory, and unused long-term memories are sometimes dumped to make room.

This would mean that dreams are highly individual in nature and very much a factor of what you have experienced during your day.